# Using date ranges from one workbook to transfer data to 2nd workbook organised by month

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

I have a workbook that contains booking information via salesperson.  It is separated out by month and within each month, each sales rep has their bookings which were signed that month listed out.  Information includes money breakdowns and production information including what date the campaign will go up.  I have to do it this way as reps are paid by how much money they sign up that month.

For the production side of our business, I would like to be able to transfer this same information into a second workbook, again sorted by month.  However the months in the second workbook would need to show which campaigns were actually taking place in that month as opposed to what was signed off.

Preferably when I update one, the other would also update automatically.

So what I want to do is for the workbook to take any row that has the value in the "Start Date" column (G) as being from, say March 2014, to then appear in full in the production workbook in March 2014.

That way we won't be doubling up on data entry.

Does that make sense?  Happy to clarify.  First question ever!

Comment: mmmmkay, so copy the entire row that has a value in column G and paste it in a _____(Different/New) Workbook on the corresponding sheet. Then move through all 12(?) sheets and repeat. yes?

Comment: Yes, and that value is a date range, for example all dates 1/02/2014 - 28/02/2014

Comment: Alright soif you want to automatic update im assuming youve already got a workbook made for it

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this works for you, from my testing, it will grap the month and year from the cell and place it into the other workbook (Make sure you change the names in the code before you do your tests) into the sheet that has `Month Year` as the sheetname.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx")

    Dim wks1 As Worksheet
    Set wks1 = wb1.ActiveSheet

    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, mntname As String, yearname As String
    i = 1
    lastrow1 = wks1.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    Do While i < lastrow1 + 1
        j = month(wks1.Range("G" & i))
        mntname = monthname(j)
        yearname = Year(Range("G" & i))
        wks1.Rows(i & ":" & i).Copy
        If wb2.Sheets(mntname & " " & yearname).Range("A1") = "" Then
        wb2.Sheets(mntname & " " & yearname).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        Else
        lastrow2 = wb2.Sheets(mntname & " " & yearname).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        wb2.Sheets(mntname & " " & yearname).Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1).PasteSpecial
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Big thanks to @Portland Runner for helping when I got stuck in the trying to get to a different workbook